# Is there any way to disable CSS Isolation in Blazor 5.0?

Tags: css, blazor

I see the option to DisableScopedCssBundling but do not see a way to disable this feature completely.

Comment: Why do you want to?  Isolation requires making correctly-named CSS files in the same folder as a component.  So. . . don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to disable it, but, on the other hand, you don't need to.

If you don't use it, it will not have effect.

It "works" build-time only, so it won't have overhead for you at runtime.

Comment: CSS Isolation means creating component-specific CSS files that as rdmptn mentions get weaved together at build time.  If you don't introduce such CSS files, you have nothing to disable.

Answer (score 3):

You can disable this feature by adding the following in csproj file

```
 <PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
<Nullable>enable</Nullable>
<ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
<ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
```

Add  false to disable

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable it and you don't need to.
If you don't want your CSS to be isolated, you can create a css file and have a `<link>` tag in your component or just use the `<style>` tag in your component like it was mentioned [here](https://blazorschool.com/tutorial/blazor-server/css-style-642406).

Answer (score 0):

To disable it [completely](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/css-isolation?view=aspnetcore-7.0#disable-css-isolation):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <ScopedCssEnabled>false</ScopedCssEnabled>
</PropertyGroup>
```

To enable it, but [disable bundling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio-code#disable-automatic-bundling):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DisableScopedCssBundling>true</DisableScopedCssBundling>
</PropertyGroup>
```

By the way, to those who commented that it doesn't hurt, and can simply be ignored... I disagree. If there's a feature one doesn't use, which is known to thrash one's disk - it creates many files on every build, and also when using hot reload - then it's a good idea to disable it.